# AngularJS Directive for twitter bootstrap form-group

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've been playing with angular lately, so far so good, but im struggling with directives.

I'm trying to create a directive that generates the html mark up for a standard bootstrap form group with its corresponding validation messages.

So basically I'm trying to convert this:

```
<form-group label="Password">
        <input type="password" data-ng-model="vm.password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control form-control-validate"
               required data-ng-minlength="6"
               data-required-error="Password is required" data-minlength-error="Your password must have at least 6 characters" />
</form-group>
```

into this:

```
<div class="form-group" data-ng-class="{'has-error': invalid}">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-2 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input data-ng-model="vm.password" type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control"
                   required data-ng-minlength="6"/>
            <div data-ng-show="changePasswordForm.$dirty && changePasswordForm.oldPassword.$invalid">
                <label data-ng-show="changePasswordForm.oldPassword.$error.required" class="label label-danger">
                    Password is required
                    <br />
                </label>
                <label data-ng-show="changePasswordForm.oldPassword.$error.minlength" class="label label-danger">
                    Your password must have at least 6 characters
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

So far this is what I have:

```
app.directive('formGroup', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'app/directives/formGroup.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        require: "^form",
        scope: {
            label: "@",
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, formController) {
            var input = element.find(":input");
            var id = input.attr("id");
            scope.for = id;
            var inputName = input.attr("name");
            // Build the scope expression that contains the validation status.
            // e.g. "form.example.$invalid"
            var inputInvalid = [formController.$name, inputName, "$invalid"].join(".");
            scope.$parent.$watch(inputInvalid, function (invalid) {
                scope.invalid = invalid;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

formGroup.html:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid }">
   <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="{{for}}">{{label}}</label>
   <div class="col-md-10">
      <div data-ng-transclude=""></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This sets correctly the bootstrap class "has-error" to the form-group if the input is invalid.

Now I want to add validation messages, and I couldn't find a way that works. This is what I have:

```
app.directive('formControlValidate', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: "app/directives/formControlValidate.html",
        restrict: 'C',
        require: ["^form", "ngModel"],
        scope: { },
        transclude: true,
        //replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controls) {
            var form = controls[0];
            var inputName = attrs.name;
            var inputErrors = [form.$name, inputName, "$error"].join(".");
            scope.$parent.$watch(inputErrors, function (newValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    scope.errors = [];
                    angular.forEach(newValue, function (value, key) {
                        var error = attrs[key + 'Error'];
                        if (value && error) {
                            scope.errors.push(error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, true);
        }
    };
```

formControlValidate.html:

```
<div class="controls" ng-transclude></div>
    <div data-ng-repeat="error in errors">
    <div class="label label-danger">
        {{error}}
    </div>
</div>
```

But this doesn't work. I'm randomly changing parameters in both directives but can't figure out what how to make it work.

Any ideas or improvements would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you put this into Plunkr or something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE:** this is my latest gist (angular 1.3): https://gist.github.com/lpsBetty/3259e966947809465cbe

---

**OLD solution:**

I tried something similiar, maybe this link can help you too: http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/create-angularjs-directives-to-remove-duplicate-codes-in-form

This was my solution. I don't know why but I had to use form.$dirty, it was not possible to use input.$dirty..
(and I use angular-translate)

HTML:

```
<form-group input="form.password">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'user.password' | translate }}" required
          name="password" ng-model="user.password" />
</form-group>
```

Directive:

```
  app.directive('formGroup', function ($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '^form', 
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        cssClass: '@class',
        input: '='
      },
      template: '<div class="form-group" ng-class="{\'has-error\':hasError, cssClass:true}">'+
                  '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
                  '<div ng-show="hasError">' +
                    '<span ng-repeat="(key,error) in input.$error" class="help-block"' +
                            'ng-show="input.$error[key]">{{\'form.invalid.\'+key | translate}}</span>' +
                  '</div>' +
                '</div>',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        var form = ctrl;
        var input = attrs.input;

        scope.$parent.$watch(input+'.$invalid', function (hasError) {
          scope.hasError = hasError && form.$dirty;
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: FWIW I was able to solve the `$dirty` issue by changing the callback function to: `function(hasError, _, parentScope) { scope.hasError = hasError && parentScope.$eval(attrs.input).$dirty; }` There might be an easier way, however.

Comment: I've created a gist for angular 1.3: https://gist.github.com/lpsBetty/3259e966947809465cbe

Comment: How would we handle clearing the form when it is submitted? I added a hook when submitting form to set the form to pristine with $.setPristine() but hasError would still be true

Comment: I've created a service for 'cleaning' the form: `angular.forEach(form, function(input) {
        if(!input) { return; }
        angular.forEach(input.$error, function(invalid, errorKey) {
          if(invalid) {
            input.$setValidity(errorKey, true);
          }
        });
      });`

Comment: not too familiar with services, could you provide examples on how its implemented?

Comment: you can inject services in your controller, and then use it like this: `formErrors.clean($scope.form); // 'form' = name of form` I updated my gist -> you can now find the service here: https://gist.github.com/lpsBetty/3259e966947809465cbe

Comment: @BettySt I have a semi-working example -> https://gist.github.com/jamesy829/66d1f01c5f4188a1b4bf, but currently it will break in the service #clean method where it loops through the form for inputs, `TypeError: Cannot read property '$error' of undefined`. it cannot loop through the form for inputs for some reason

Comment: @jamesy829 sorry i forgot this line: https://gist.github.com/lpsBetty/3259e966947809465cbe#file-formerrorssvc-js-L37   I don't know how an input can be undefined, but I only had this problem with angular 1.3