# AngularJS password confirmation noMatch working but form is $invalid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-validation

I am using this code to make password input and confirm password input to match correctly

Javascript:

```
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('validPasswordC', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {

      reference: '=validPasswordC'

    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue, $scope) {

        var noMatch = viewValue != scope.reference
        ctrl.$setValidity('noMatch', !noMatch)
      });

      scope.$watch("reference", function(value) {;
        ctrl.$setValidity('noMatch', value === ctrl.$viewValue);

      });
    }
  }
});
 app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.submit= function (form) {
        if(form.$valid)
        alert('in');
        else
            alert('out');
    }
    });
```

HTML:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <p>Password:{{formData.password}}</p>
    <form name="signupForm" ng-submit="submit(signupForm)">
      <div class="fieldset" ng-class="{'has-error':formData.password.$invalid && !formData.password.$pristine}">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" ng-model="formData.password" ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="20" ng-pattern="/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])/" placeholder="password" required />

        <p ng-show="signupForm.password.$error.required" class="error">*</p>
        <p ng-show="signupForm.password.$error.minlength" class="error">
          Passwords must be between 8 and 20 characters.</p>
        <p ng-show="signupForm.password.$error.pattern" class="error">
          Must contain one lower &amp; uppercase letter, and one non-alpha character (a number or a symbol.)</p>
      </div>

      <div class="fieldset" ng-class="{'has-error':formData.password_c.$invalid && !formData.password_c.$pristine}">
        <label for="password_c">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password_c" name="password_c" ng-model="formData.password_c" placeholder="confirm password" valid-password-c="formData.password" required />

        <p ng-show="signupForm.password_c.$error.noMatch" class="error">Passwords do not match.</span>
          <p ng-show="signupForm.password_c.$error.required" class="error">*</p>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code is working fine but when I pass form to ng-submit function it always says invalid at confirm password field . I check this form in console only confirm password field has $valid = false and $invalid = true . Need help what is wrong here.

Here is the console

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at $error? That should tell you exactly what is failing

Comment: Its really hard to understand there

Comment: can you add that to the question? Perhaps someone can help you understand that

Comment: Added the image for confirm password field

Comment: Ok, from the $error, we can see parse is set to true. Which means the cause is in your $parsers function. I see you pass into the function $scope, but then make reference to scope. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why you use `$parsers` instead of [`$validators`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validators)? Parsers are used for formatting not for validating an input field! Here's my solution:

```
/**
 * Validator for matching two inputs.
 * The given attribute is the value to match the own modelValue.
 * @example
 *   <input name="passwordConfirm" type="password" ng-model="passwordConf" validate-match="newPassword">
 */
app.directive('validateMatch', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      validateMatch: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

      scope.$watch('validateMatch', function() {
        ngModel.$validate(); // validate again when match value changes
      });

      ngModel.$validators.match = function(modelValue) {
        if (!modelValue || !scope.validateMatch || ngModel.$error.minlength) {
          return true;
        }
        return modelValue === scope.validateMatch;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

The `$error` attribute is named `match` not `noMatch` because that would be double negative.

Comment: the ``ngModel.$validators.match`` function checks the equality of the given model and the actual model value.

Comment: signupForm.passwordConfirm.$error.match this works for errors

Comment: it also works for ``signupForm.$invalid`` or ``signupForm.passwordConfirm.$invalid``!

Comment: I also recommend using a directive for form-groups (if you are using bootstrap) @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22658021/595152

Answer (score 1):

The specific error you're seeing is because you are using $parsers incorrectly, you should be using $validators as mentioned in Betty St's answer.

From the angular documentation [for $Parsers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers)

> Returning undefined from a parser means a parse error occurred.

Note that the function you unshift to $parsers has no return, meaning it returns undefined, which is interpreted as a parse error. (exactly as the $error object indicates)

Comment: Betty St's answer details how to use the match Validator. It just needs to be updated to your specific naming.