# How to check validation on fields , selected values can not be same?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have to check validation on two fields with ng-change. The selected values cannot be same so i have implemented below logic but this function is not even being called. Its been hours and i cannot figure out what i am doing wrong. Please check if logic is being implemented correctly.

So far tried code....

main.html

```
<div class="panel-body">
        <form name="addAttesForm" id="addAttesForm" novalidate k-validate-on-blur="false">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="roleType" class="col-md-4">Role Type:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <select 
                                    kendo-drop-down-list
                                    data-text-field="'text'"
                                    data-value-field="'id'" name="roleType"
                                    k-option-label="'Select'"
                                    k-data-source="roleTypeDataSource"
                                    ng-model="attestorDTO.riskAssessmentRoleTypeKey"
                                    id="roleType">          
                                </select>   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="attestorWorker" class="col-md-4">Attestor:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="attestorWorker" required
                                    ng-model="attestorDTO.attestorWorker" name="attestorWorker"
                                    ng-change="validateProxy('attestorWorker','proxyWorker')"
                                    ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
                                    ng-click="openAttestorSearch()"  readonly="readonly"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="proxyWorker" class="col-md-4">Proxy :</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="proxyWorker" required
                                    ng-model="attestorDTO.proxyWorker" name="proxyWorker"
                                    ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
                                    ng-click="openProxySearch()" ng-disabled="!attestorDTO.attestorWorker" ng-change="validateProxy('attestorWorker','proxyWorker')" readonly="readonly"/>
                                    <p class="text-danger" ng-show="addAttesForm.proxyWorker.$error.dateRange">Attestor and Proxy can not be same</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button" ng-disabled="addAttesForm.$invalid" ng-click="saveAttestor()">Add attestor</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

main.js

```
$scope.validateProxy = function(startField, endField) {
        console.log("calling validation...");
        var isValid = ($scope.attestorDTO[startField]) <= ($scope.attestorDTO[endField]);
        $scope.addAttesForm[endField].$setValidity('dateRange',isValid);
        $scope.addAttesForm.$setValidity('dateRange',isValid);
    };
```

Comment: the right way is to use a directive for validations, maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467088/angularjs-password-confirmation-nomatch-working-but-form-is-invalid/30467774#30467774

Comment: Do we have solution other than directive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the readonly attribute. ng-change will not fire on the readonly input elements and the model should be changed via the UI not by the javascript code.

Try like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="attestorWorker" required
                                    ng-model="attestorDTO.attestorWorker" name="attestorWorker"
                                    ng-change="validateProxy('attestorWorker','proxyWorker')"
                                    ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
                                    ng-click="openAttestorSearch()" />

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="proxyWorker" required
                                    ng-model="attestorDTO.proxyWorker" name="proxyWorker"
                                    ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
                                    ng-click="openProxySearch()" ng-disabled="!attestorDTO.attestorWorker" ng-change="validateProxy('attestorWorker','proxyWorker')" />
```